# Phpspec global composer install not working

Tags: php, macos, testing, macos-catalina, phpspec

I have installed phpspec through composer within codebase root by doing `composer require phpspec/phpspec`. I wanted to run it without prefixing it each time with `vendor/bin`, but I also didn't want to add that to `PATH`, so I installed it globally first with `composer global require phpspec/phpspec` (both versions are the same) and added to path with `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` (I am on MacOS Catalina).

Now I can run `phpspec` from the codebase root, and it does indeed run. I can run `phpspec describe xxx` which does create a file and works, however doing a `phpspec run` fails miserably:

```
✘ Fatal error happened while executing the following

    Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher::dispatch() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event or null, string given, called in /Users/.../.composer/vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Util/DispatchTrait.php on line 22 and defined in /Users/.../.composer/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/.../.composer/vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Util/DispatchTrait.php(22): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(Object(PhpSpec\Event\SuiteEvent), 'beforeSuite')
#1 /Users/.../.composer/vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Runner/SuiteRunner.php(52): PhpSpec\Runner\SuiteRunner->dispatch(Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher), Object(PhpSpec\Event\SuiteEvent), 'beforeSuite')
#2 /Users/.../.composer/vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Console/Command/RunCommand.php(178): PhpSpec\Runner\SuiteRunner->run(Object(PhpSpec\Loader\Suite))
#3 /Users/.../.composer/ven in /Users/.../.composer/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 37
```

However running `vendor/bin/phpspec run` goes through fine.

What might be the error here?

Comment: What makes you think that `phpspec` and `vendor/bin/phpspec` point to the same instance?

Comment: Additionally, there is a bug report at https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/1294 which matches the given error

Comment: I never said they point to same instance. Obviously those are 2 separate dependencies (but same version nevertheless). I'm baffled as to why the same code behaves differently depending on location

Comment: Maybe, the vendor version pulls in more stuff from the rest of your application, such that even the exact same version of phpspec uses different depending packages?

Comment: My "app" is literally a composer file with phpspec dependency. Even with that in mind it is strange how `describe` option does work in both cases though

Comment: I have the same problem. Thanks for asking the question.